# Como selecionar o nome e o salário do empregado de 'MG' que recebe o maior salário?

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma tabela com as colunas `nome`, `salario` e `alocacao`.

Como faço para selecionar somente o trabalhador que tem o maior salário e que tem o valor `mg` na coluna `alocacao`, sem usar `MAX()`?

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT 
     nome, salario 
FROM empregados 
WHERE alocacao="mg" 
ORDER BY salario DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

**Por partes:**

- `nome`, `salario`, as colunas que queres que apareçam no resultado
- `FROM empregados`, o nome da tabela
- `WHERE alocacao="mg"`, a condição a verifcar, ie. só trazer resultado(s) que tênha(m) o valor da coluna `alocacao` igual a `mg``
- `ORDER BY salario`, ordenar pelo valor da coluna `salario`
- `DESC`, fazer a ordenação ser por ordem decrescente (do maior para o mais pequeno)
- `LIMIT 1`, trazer só um resultado